# What is the world state in corda like in hyperledger fabric the world state is the snap of the ledger

Tags: spring-boot, blockchain, corda

so consider that we create a state in corda and that have multiple schemas, now consider that one schema have attributes empid,name and address now if he changes his address 3 times then that will be updated in ledger 3 times now if the api want the latest data that is the api only want the latest address of the employ now all the 3 address the this logic should be implemented in corda or api layer.

condenser the  case of hyperledger fabric the current/world sate will give the latest data to query so that it does not have to go to ledger so is their anything like that in corda

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Fabric, there is no world state in Corda. Corda emphasizes privacy, hence nodes only knows about the data they are concerned about. Having said that the platform ensures that a common data shared between multiple nodes are always in sync.

Corda uses states to record facts, states are immutable thus facts update means the existing state is consumed and a new state is created with the updated information (UTXO model like in bitcoin).

Now considering your example of address update, it doesn't matter if its updated one would always get the latest version of the address (unless otherwise specified) when the node is queried.